# Optimistic locking without version field

Tags: mysql, jdbc, optimistic-locking

I have a table with a status field

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `id` BIGINT(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT;
```

Status can have values such as

```
 DRAFT, POSTED, DELTED
```

I want to implement locking so that only one transaction can update the status at one time. I am using java and jdbc. Below is the converted sql from my code.

```
start transaction;
update db_example.new_table set value=100, status='POSTED' where name="b" and status='DRAFT';
commit;
```

Code :

```
myRepo.executeInTransaction(()->{
  Update update = new Update();
  update.set("value", 100);
  update.set("status", "POSTED);
  Criteria criteria = TSqlUtils.newCriteria("name");
  criteria.is("b").and("status").is("DRAFT");
  // DO something in another table 
  ...
  // 
  int count = this.mysqlDao.update(this.getJdbcTemplate(), Query.from(criteria), update, MyObject.class);
  if(count == 0){
    throw new TException("Conflicting transaction");
  }
});
```

If I check only on the basis of status, is it enough for locking?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Transactions are relevant when you have more than one thing to do (including things in java), optimistic locking is a way to increase concurrency (by locking less). Your code neither seems to be actually doing optimistic locking nor is it clear if you need it. You may be overthinking your problem. Maybe describe your problem, e.g. show a (pessimistic locking) transaction that you want to optimize because you expect heavy concurrency (and where optimistic locking might be one way to solve it).

Comment: @Solarflare, I want to update the status of a row. Instead of having version column, I am trying to do only based on the previous status. This might have multiple rows to update. My question is , is it enough to do based on status or should I add version column?

Comment: This checks if you updated at least one row. It has nothing to do with optimistic locking though - at least not without context, e.g. the point in time you compare against. If there is such a previous state, it is doubtful your code would be correct, as a lot of modifications would not be cought (only) by this (e.g. someone adding or removing a row (if there were more than 1) with "b" & "draft". Your code still might do what you expect it to do, but at least I do not know (exactly) what you expect it to do. Or, simplified: How would your code look *with* a version field?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you first need to decide on the business requirement. If two threads decide to update the status at the same time what needs to happen?

For instance last modifier wins is a common solution. Another solution may be to refuse the second modification and return an informative error to the second process.

Once this is sorted the code naturally follows.

Comment: I need to throw an error if two threads are updating at same time. One will be successful another will be rejected.